# Retrieve my Minecraft world after forcing to shut down my PC

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Yesterday I was playing on one of my Minecraft worlds. After a few minutes, my PC froze and nothing on the screen would move. After about 40 minutes, my screen was  completely frozen and I decided to force my PC to shut down. When I started Minecraft again, my world had disappeared off the list. I then went on the "%appdata%" files, under ".minecraft" and "saves," and saw my world in the list! How can I get the world file shown in that folder to appear in the list of worlds in the game?